# Using in operator to match items in a tuple

Tags: python, tuples, matching

I am trying to understand why the in operator below does not also match and print (4, 'foobar'), and ('foobar', 5) (it matches the rest). Trying to nail down my understanding of the in with tuples. I was trying to match all tuples that had "foo" or "bar", or "foobar" in any part of the tuple.

```
ls = [(1, 'foo'), ('bar2'), ('foo', 'bar', 3), (4, 'foobar'), ('foobar', 5), ('foobar')]
print [x for x in ls if 'foo' in x or 'bar' in x]
```

> ```
> [(1, 'foo'), 'bar2', ('foo', 'bar', 3), 'foobar']
> ```

Comment: `('bar2')` is *not* a tuple containing `'bar2'`. It is literally (no pun intended) the string `'bar2'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a tuple, `'foo' in x` means "is there an element of `x` that **equals** `'foo'`", not "is there an element of `x` that **contains** `'foo'`".

To do the latter, you could do something like

```
any('foo' in y for y in x)
```

However, for a string, `'foo' in x` means "is `'foo'` a substring of `x`".

Additionally, a single element in parentheses (e.g. `('bar2')` and `('foobar')`) does *not* make a tuple. To make a tuple, you generally need a comma in the parentheses: `('bar2',)` and `('foobar',)`. Both of these elements match because they are not tuples and contain the right substring.

If you are looking specifically for `foo`, `bar` and `foobar`, not something like `barfoo`, just add an additional `or` to the comprehension:

```
[x for x in ls if 'foo' in x or 'bar' in x or 'foobar' in x]
```

You could generalize using `any` by doing something like

```
search_terms = ('foo', 'bar', 'foobar')
[x for x in ls if any(a in x for a in search_terms)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Because ('bar2') is not a tuple, but just the string 'bar2' (and 'bar' is in that string), while ('foobar', 1) is a tuple and 'bar' is not one of ('foobar', 1).

'in' works differently on a list/tuple and on a single string. When applied to a string, it asks "is 'foo' a substring?". When applied to a list/tuple, it asks "is 'foo' equal to one of the list/tuple items?".